# Custom Vue select component not updating selected option when v-model value changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

I'm trying to wrap a select in a Vue custom component using the `v-model` pattern as described [in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components).

The problem I'm facing is that I get the following error message for my custom select component:

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be
> overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a
> data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being
> mutated: "value"
>
> found in
>
> --->

However, when I make `value` a data property, I loose the expected functionality.  That is, when the bound value changes, the select box doesn't update.  The two-way binding is lost.

What is the correct way to maintain the behavior I am expecting without raising warnings?

Here is an interactive example demonstrating the problem (best seen in full screen).

```js
Vue.component('dynamic-select-ex1', {
  template: '#dynamic-select-template',
  props: ['value', 'options'],
  methods: {
    changed() {
      // custom input components need to emit the input event
      this.$emit('input', event.target.value)
    },
  },
})

Vue.component('dynamic-select-ex2', {
  template: '#dynamic-select-template',
  props: ['options'],
  data() {
    return {
      value: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changed() {
      // custom input components need to emit the input event
      this.$emit('input', event.target.value)
    },
  },
})

let example = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data() {
    return {
      selected: null,
      options: [
        { text: 'Hello', value: 1 },
        { text: 'World', value: 2 },
        { text: 'Blah', value: 3 },
        { text: 'Blerg', value: 4 },
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
   text() {
     if (!this.selected) return
     return this.options.find(({ value }) => value == this.selected).text
   },
  },
  methods: {
    select(value) {
      this.selected = value
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="dynamic-select-template">
  <select v-model="value" @change="changed">
    <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">{{ option.text }}</option>
  </select>
</script>

<div id="example">
  <label for="direct">Vue behaviour for native select</label><br>
  <select id="direct" v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">{{ option.text }}</option>
  </select><br>

  <div>Vue behaviour for custom component. `value` is a prop. Warning output in console when user selects option</div>
  <dynamic-select-ex1 v-model="selected" :options="options"></dynamic-select-ex1><br>

  <div>Vue behaviour for custom component. `value` is a data property. two-way binding is broken.  Selected option not updated when `value` changes.</div>
  <dynamic-select-ex2 v-model="selected" :options="options"></dynamic-select-ex2><br>
  
  <br>Selected: {{ text }}<br><br>
  
  <button @click="select(1)">Hello</button>
  <button @click="select(2)">World</button>
  <button @click="select(3)">Blah</button>
  <button @click="select(4)">Blerg</button><br>

</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Computed Setter

For `v-model`, use a [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) with `v-model` instead of `value`, to avoid mutating the prop.
You can get rid of the `change` listener.

```html
<select v-model="model">
  <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">{{ option.text }}</option>
</select>
```

```js
Vue.component('dynamic-select-ex1', {
  template: '#dynamic-select-template',
  props: ['value', 'options'],
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() { return this.value },
      set(value) { this.$emit('input', value) }
    }
  }
})
```

When the computed value is accessed, it returns the prop value, and when it's set, it emits instead.

#### Or `:value`, `@input`, and `$event.target.value`

Another option is to make a 1-way binding of `value` and `$emit` from the template:

```html
<select :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
  <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">{{ option.text }}</option>
</select>
```

```js
Vue.component('dynamic-select-ex1', {
  template: '#dynamic-select-template',
  props: ['value', 'options'],
})
```

Comment: Thanks!  That works exactly as `v-model` does on a native select :)

Comment: You're welcome :) I added another option that doesn't use `v-model`

Comment: That second option is much cleaner :)